# How is Ruby programming language release versioned?

Tags: ruby

[Ruby Releases](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/) lists all released Ruby versions. It has all the versions for `2.7.x`:

```
Ruby 2.7.5  2021-11-24
Ruby 2.7.4  2021-07-07
...
```

Does it mean that there is only one build for one `2.7.x` version? For example, `2.7.5` has only `2021-11-24` build and `2.7.4` has only `2021-07-07` build. And if there is a new build for `2.7.x,` it will be Ruby `2.7.6`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: @pjs [The tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) says "Ask about... Software development tools" and I think this question would fall under that. Maybe in the gray area but not 100% off topic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [ruby versioning policy](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/21/ruby-version-policy-changes-with-2-1-0/). There are MAJOR, MINOR, TEENY and PATCH version numbers. So it is very likely there are several 2.7.4 patches - and you'll want the latest.

Comment: Since 2.1.0 each released MAJOR.MINOR.TEENY has only one release (date). PATCH is only of interest if unreleased versions are used (e.g. testing/developing a bug fix or a new feature). So there's only one 2.7.4 but there are multiple 2.0.0 with an ascending patch level.